# Simple routing issue with Debian

Tags: networking, router, debian, routing

I'm working on an assignment for a networking course and I'm having difficulties with one of the first steps, something really basic.

I have three VM's one running Debian (to serve as the router), one running Windows Server 2012 and the other is a client running Windows 8.

I'm trying to enable connectivity between the Server and the client but I can't seem to figure it out.

I know I have to configure some sort of static route between the two interfaces, but beyond there I am stooped. I have attached a simple diagram I quickly whipped up in paint to explain it a bit better.

Eventually, I will need to install DHCP on the server and the have the client obtain an address dynamically rather than the static one I've set.

On the router, I've disabled NAT and enabled IPV4 forwarding.

What have I missed?

Here is a simple diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the bare minimum, the client must have a route towards the server, and the server must have a route towards the client. If both already use Router as their "default gateway", that should already be enough.

But if they use a *different* gateway for their default route, then you'll need to add specific ones which will go through this Router:

- on the client, `192.168.1.108/30 via 172.16.28.1` (router's IP from client perspective)
- likewise on the server, `172.16.28.0/25 via 192.168.1.109`

If you had a Linux-based client, you could use `ip route get <ip>` and `ip route show match <ip>` to easily see the routing decisions it would make.